# Как правильно разложить функцию в степенной ряд?

Tags: c++, математика, ряды

Хочу написать разложение в степенной ряд функцию `ln(x+1)` по известной всем формуле (можно посмотреть на сайте http://edu.sernam.ru/book_p_math2.php?id=81). Либо я не понимаю смысл разложения, либо что-то делаю не так, но итоговый ответ не удовлетворяет. Программа, по сути, простая.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");

    double x, val, sum = 0;
    int i;
    cin >> x;
    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        val = (pow(-1, (i + 1))*pow(x, i)) / i;
        cout << " " << val;
        sum += val;
        cout << " " << sum << endl;
    }
    cout << "Логарифм мой: " << sum << endl;
    cout << "Логарифм реальный: " << log(x+1);

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ввод, вывод? не удовлетворяет?

Comment: вывод, конечно, если, например, задать x=2, т.е. считаем ln(3), ответ должен быть приблизительно 1.1, но вместо него появляется огромнейшее число

Comment: Вы не дочитали Вашу собственную ссылку: "Это равенство справедливо ..."

Comment: @Igor, точно, спасибо

Comment: `Таким образам, мы можем получить натуралыгае логарифмы любых целых чисел.` Это скан такой, или в оригинале так?

Comment: @vp_arth, видимо, оригинал, я просто привёл пример сайта, где можно посмотреть степенной ряд, в теорию не углублялся

Answer (score 5):

Видимо, вы забываете, что этот ряд сходится только для `|x|<1`.
У вас считает правильно, но несколько неоптимально, так что я переписал заново.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x;
    cout << "Input x (-1,1): ";
    cin >> x;
    if (fabs(x) >= 1.0)
    {
        cerr << "Wrong value\n";
        return 1;
    }
    double sum = x, term = x;
    double eps = 1e-8;
    for(int k = 2; fabs(term)/sum >= eps ; ++k)
    {
        sum += term *= -x*(k-1)/k;
    }
    cout << "Sum is      " << setprecision(10) << sum << endl;
    cout << "Log(1+x) is " << setprecision(10) << log(1+x) << endl;

}
```

Comment: что значит неоптимально? хочу это учесть в следующий раз

Comment: 1. Использует (дважды!!) функцию `pow`, без которой можно обойтись, и которая дает только тормоза... 2. Считает для реальных значений совершенно лишние члены - например, для 0.5 последние члены - порядка 10 в -35 степени - явно лишнее.